# My Accordion doesnt seem to work. Clicked but nothing happen. it doesnt go thru the js

Tags: javascript, html, accordion

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-section">
      <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-1">Test</a>
      <div class="accordion-section-content" id="accordion-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My JS (which i took from http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-an-accordion-with-html-css-jquery):

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    function close_accordion_section() {
        jQuery('.accordion .accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
        jQuery('.accordion .accordion-section-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
    }

    jQuery('.accordion-section-title').click(function(e) {
        // Grab current anchor value
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        if(jQuery(e.target).is('.active')) {
            close_accordion_section();
        }else {
            close_accordion_section();

            jQuery(this).addClass('active');

            jQuery('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open'); 
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Try putting e.preventDefault(); at the beginning , before currentAttrValue

Answer (score 0):

The code that you've posted looks fine to me. Be sure to include the jQuery JS file on your page at the end of the  tag.